# Models of confinement based on negative mass carriers

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, confinement, carrier-particles

In the old Yukawa model of nuclear forces, it was proposed that [short-range interactions were mediated by exchanges using massive force carriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukawa_potential) (originally, mesons were proposed for this).

If one considers a Yukawa potential with negative carrier mass, one is left with an effective confinement potential

Is there a reason to expect gluons to have effectively negative mass (at least while considering the long distances/IR limit)? Have negative mass carriers been proposed to model confinement?

Comment: What about virtual particles in  in feynman diagrams? can  go through negative masses as they are off mass shell.